# Filter Array of Objects containing resolved Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a bunch of objects in a array like this:

```
let orders = [];
orders.push({
    name: 'name1',
    promise: promiseFunction(1),
    description: 'description1'
});
orders.push({
    name: 'name2',
    promise: promiseFunction(2),
    description: 'description2'
});
```

I previously waited for every Promise to resolve:

```
await Promise.allSettled(orders.map(order => order.promise));
```

which works fine.

But now I'd like to have an array with all `orders` that have a resolved Promise.
How would I filter this?
Pseudo-code-ish I thought about something like this:

```
let successfullMainOrders = orders.filter(order => order.promise == 'resolved');
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

To add some context: I'm trying to send multiple REST requests as fast as possible. This is done with a function that either resolves or rejects with the requests result. (`promisefunction()`)
Since I want to make those requests no matter if one fails as fast as possible, my idea was to collect them first in an array `orders` with some aditional information for identification later like `name` and `description` and after every request either resolved/rejected `await Promise.allSettled(orders.map(order => order.promise));` I want to do further operations only with information from successfull requests.

Comment: Promises do not offer any method of synchronous introspection for the internal state. You'll need to keep track when each promise you're interested in settles and store that state externally to the promise instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code will not work because `orders` is an object, not an array. You can't `.push` to an object.

To wait for all resolve values and have an array as the result with the values in addition to the other parts of the object, put a `.then` after each Promise to resolve to one of the objects in the array, eg:

```
const orders = await Promise.all([
  promiseFunction(1).then(val => ({ name: 'name1', val, description: 'description1' })),
  promiseFunction(2).then(val => ({ name: 'name2', val, description: 'description2' })),
]);
```

If you're able to generalize your code to use an array of names, descriptions, and `promiseFunction` arguments to call, you can make it less repetitive, maybe something like

```
const initialOrders = [
  { name: 'name1', arg: 1, description: 'description1' },
  { name: 'name2', arg: 2, description: 'description2' },
];
const orders = await Promise.all(
  initialOrders.map(
    ({ arg, ...rest }) => promiseFunction(arg).then(
      val => ({ ...rest, val })
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry... `oders` is an array ofc... So my guess is just from looking at this code all rejected Promises will not end up in `orders` which would be exactly what I need. I'll test this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to synchronously determine if a promise has been resolved is to wrap it.

```js
let wrapPromise = promise => {
  promise.resolved = promise.rejected = false;
  promise.then(() => promise.resolved = true);
  promise.catch(() => promise.rejected = true);
  return promise;
};

let asyncMultiplyBy10 = a =>
  wrapPromise(new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(a * 10), 1)));

let orders = [];
orders.push({
  name: 'name1',
  promise: asyncMultiplyBy10(1),
  description: 'description1'
});
orders.push({
  name: 'name2',
  promise: asyncMultiplyBy10(2),
  description: 'description2'
});

console.log(orders[0].promise.resolved); // false
setTimeout(() => console.log(orders[0].promise.resolved), 2); // true
```

You can even define a class to replace `Promise`

```js
class PromiseX {
  constructor(func) {
    let promise = new Promise(func);
    promise.resolved = promise.rejected = false;
    promise.then(() => promise.resolved = true);
    promise.catch(() => promise.rejected = true);
    return promise;
  }
}

let p = new PromiseX(r => setTimeout(r, 1));

console.log(p.resolved);
setTimeout(() => console.log(p.resolved), 2);
```

Taking this further, you can even add the `resolve` and `reject` functions to the promise wrapper to make it easier to resolve outside of construction.

```js
class PromiseX {
  constructor() {
    let resolve, reject;
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      resolve = res;
      reject = rej;
    });
    promise.resolve = (...a) => {
      if (!promise.rejected)
        promise.resolved = true;
      resolve(...a);
    };
    promise.reject = (...a) => {
      if (!promise.resolved)
        promise.rejected = true;
      reject(...a);
    };
    promise.resolved = promise.rejected = false;
    promise.then(() => promise.resolved = true);
    promise.catch(() => promise.rejected = true);

    return promise;
  }
}

let p = new PromiseX();

console.log(p.resolved);
p.resolve(10);
console.log(p.resolved);
```

And lastly, you can use any of a number of npm modules designed to handle arrays/streams of promises (or promises of arrays of promises of arrays ...).

E.g., with [npm's bs-better-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-better-stream)

```
let stream = new Stream();
stream.writePromise(Promise.resolve(3), Promise.resolve(4), Promise.resolve(5));
stream.each(a => console.log(a));
// prints '3', '4', '5' immediately

let promise = new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(6), 1000));
stream.writePromise(promise, Promise.resolve(7));
// prints '7' immediately
// prints '6' 1 second later
```

Comment: your wrappers are over-simplified and swallow errors. You can't simply write `promise.catch(() => promise.rejected = true)` without bubbling up the error. Sure this marks `promise.rejected` as `true`, but it also turns any rejected promise into a resolved `true`. You have to change this to `promise.catch(e => { promise.rejected = true; return Promise.reject(e))`. In other words, `.catch` takes an rejected promise and "catches" it, and safely puts it back on the path of success. If you call `.catch` and intend to keep the promise rejected, you have to reject the error.

Comment: Your `PromiseX` implementation makes the same sort of mistake. To add to that, `if (!promise.rejected) ...` and `if (!promise.resolved)` are not sufficient. You also have to prevent double resolve and double reject. All this is to say it's hard to implement data structures and get them right. I wouldn't steer a learner down this path unless you are prepared to cover all of these bases.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Roberts offers you an insightful comment that you should not ignore. You are using Promises in an unconventional way and there's likely a better way to solve the problem. You would need to explain your situation with more detail and perhaps provide code before and after this step if we are to help you more effectively.

However this is your bed and you can lay in it if you want to. Let's proceed assuming there is no other way. Say we have an array of two `orders` where the `promise` field of each order is a pending promise -

```js
const orders =
  [ { name: 'name1',
      promise: promiseFunction(1000),
      description: 'description1'
    },
    { name: 'name2',
      promise: promiseFunction(5000),
      description: 'description2'
    }
  ]
```

Where the example `promiseFunction` resolves in the specified number of milliseconds, `ms` -

```js
const promiseFunction = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms, ms))
```

Now `forEach` of the `orders`, we can overwrite the order's `promise` field with the resolved value -

```js
orders.forEach((o, i) => o.promise.then(v => o.promise = v))
```

After 3 seconds, we would expect the first order to be resolved and the second order is still pending -

```js
setTimeout
  ( _ => {
      console.log("3 seconds into the future...")
      const completed = orders.filter(o => !(o.promise instanceof Promise))
      console.log("completed", completed)
    }
  , 3000
  )
```

```js
"3 seconds into the future..."
"completed" [
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "promise": 1000,
    "description": "description1"
  }
]
```

And after 10 seconds, we should see that both orders have resolved -

```js
setTimeout
  ( _ => {
      console.log("10 seconds into the future...")
      const completed = orders.filter(o => !(o.promise instanceof Promise))
      console.log("completed", completed)
    }
  , 10000
  )
```

```js
"10 seconds into the future..."
"completed" [
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "promise": 1000,
    "description": "description1"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "promise": 5000,
    "description": "description2"
  }
]
```

Expand the snippet to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const promiseFunction = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms, ms))

const orders =
  [ { name: 'name1',
      promise: promiseFunction(1000),
      description: 'description1'
    },
    { name: 'name2',
      promise: promiseFunction(5000),
      description: 'description2'
    }
  ]

orders.forEach((o, i) => o.promise.then(v => o.promise = v))

setTimeout
  ( _ => {
      console.log("3 seconds into the future...")
      const completed = orders.filter(o => !(o.promise instanceof Promise))
      console.log("completed", completed)
    }
  , 3000
  )
  
setTimeout
  ( _ => {
      console.log("10 seconds into the future...")
      const completed = orders.filter(o => !(o.promise instanceof Promise))
      console.log("completed", completed)
    }
  , 10000
  )
  
console.log("loading...")
```

I should emphasize this does nothing to handle errors, in the event they should happen in your actual code. Again, it's hard to advise you because we are seeing your problem through a pinhole and it seems you are misusing promises. Seek CertainPerformance's answer for an alternative but I would strongly recommend against junvar's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will reconsider my usage of Promises - using them in this particular fashion at least. But may I ask why you would strongly advise against junvar's answer? Wrapping promises does not seem to be such a farfetched idea as I have seen it in other places (e.g. medium.com/@jesterxl/easier-error-handling-using-async-await-b9ab0cb938e)

Comment: Also I added some context for my use case on my original question.

Comment: @FabZbi I left comments on his/her answer to support my recommendation. Wrapping the promise is a novel idea but it's hard to get right in a way that doesn't introduce hard-to-see consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the result of the promises array by the `status` property for the `fulfilled` promises:

```js
let orders = [];

const promiseFunction = (x) => {
  if(x) {
    return Promise.resolve(x);
  } else {
    return Promise.reject('err');
  }
}

orders.push({
    name: 'name1',
    promise: promiseFunction(10),
    description: 'description1'
});
orders.push({
    name: 'name2',
    promise: promiseFunction(0),
    description: 'description2'
});

(async () => {
  const arr = (await (Promise.allSettled(orders.map(order => order.promise)))).filter(({ status }) => status === 'fulfilled')
  console.log(arr);
})()
```